# am I right understand int(M)?

Tags: mysql

Can you reply to some of my questions?

1. If i declare a field `int(1) unsigned` or `int(11) unsigned`, in both case I can store from `0 to 4294967295` digit?
2. `int(1)` means that I can see only 1 digit of my number in the mysql editor? so with `int(11)` can I see 11 digit? But if I can store max 4294967295 (10 digit) what mean 11?
3. the storage memory is always `4 byte` (if I store, for example, 134 or 4294967295, the space required is the same)?

Tried to read the official Manual, but is not so clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number of digits has sense when you use zerofill attribute for left padding. 
It doesn't influence the range of values.

Max value available depends even if you use unsigned or not.

Comment: I don't use that zerofill attribute. So is it better use int(1), int(11) or nothing change?

Comment: if you don't use zerofill attribute you can omit to specify number of digits. Nothing changes. Ciao!

Comment: I think I must put a value, else the MySql put a default value (10). Is there any good manual to understand this behaviour?

Comment: As I already wrote you, you don't have to worry about int "size" if you don't need padding. Take a look at this article http://ebergen.net/wordpress/2005/07/29/mysql-int11-and-int3-store-the-same-values/

Comment: Good document! Finally I see how that M means! thanks nick rulez ;)

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes
2. Integers can be negative, needing a sign
3. yes